# Winforms deforming when switch from desktop monitor to Laptop HDPI monitors

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface

So I have a winform app works great when laptop is docked and using desktop monitors even on giant 4k monitors.   As soon as the user has to use the app on the laptop the UI goes haywire.  See photos.

[Laptop Screen messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGIOZ.jpg)

[Normal on desktop monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POiky.jpg)

I have searched and tried all the suggestions to no avail.  With remote work very popular right now this is crippling my app.

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft- 
com:asm.v1">
<assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
   <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
</trustInfo>
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
<application>
  <!-- Windows 10 -->
<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />
</application>
</compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Autoscale set to none.  .Net framework 4.8

Comment: Are you using any start window position in your form properties?
How are the layout properties set? What is your .net version?

Comment: I am using center screen for start position in most forms.   Most forms are MDI children of the main from some are not.  Autosize set to grow only.  Have tried autoscale set to none.  Most layout done with drag and drop in visual studio.  Some anchors set.  .net framework 4.8

Comment: Do you have a manifest file in your project? If yes, share the non-commented content of the file. What's the value of [AutoScaleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of your form? What version of .NET or .NET Framework? (Please add the details to the question.)

Comment: You may want to look at: [Setting default awareness with the application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#setting-default-awareness-with-the-application-manifest)

Comment: Following those steps to make app dpi aware will report back.

Comment: This did not fix the issue.